# PHPUnit Mocking Wrapper Instances

Tags: phpunit, integration-testing

I have this wrapper:

```
class APIWrapper {
    protected static $clientClass = \Hardcoded_API; // from a library
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new self::$clientClass(array_merge(self::$config, $config));
    }

    /**
     * Does something.
     *
     * @throws SomeException
     */
    public function act() {
         $this->client->doSomething();
    }

    public static function setClientClass($clientClass) {
         self::$clientClass = $clientClass;
    }
}
```

Now let's say I am testing functions that make use of this wrapper:

```
class UnrelatedFunction {
    public function callAPI() {
        $wrapper = new APIWrapper();
        try {
            $wrapper->act();
        } catch (SomeException $e) {
            // ... do other things
        }
    }
}

class UnrelatedFunctionsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testUnrelatedFunctionException() {
        $unrelatedFunction = new UnrelatedFunction();
        $this->setExpectedException('SomeException');
        // this call triggers the APIWrapper
        $unrelatedFunction->callAPI();

        // Some assertions here...
    }
}
```

I need to be able to verify that `UnrelatedFunction::callAPI()` did its job recovering from the exception. In this case, how can I mock a `\Hardcoded_API` class, make it throw a `SomeException` when `act()` is called, and pass it onto `APIWrapper::setClientClass()` so that I can test the behaviour?

Comment: I would strongly suggest re-writing the whole code to use DI and Factory to achieve what you want. It is going to be a lot easier to test the code. Having said that you can try playing with `setMockClassName` to do what you need in your current implementation.

Comment: @awnos Is this not DI? I cannot change `Hardcoded_API` as it is from another library so I have the option for the Factory to change the client class needed.

Comment: I think I need to be more clear. Your `APIWrapper` class should take `Hardcoded_API` as an constructor argument. Then you can easily mock the `Hardcoded_API` lib class and inject it to your wrapper. Same for `UnrelatedFunction`. It shouldn't construct `APIWrapper` but take it as an constructor argument or utilize another factory class that knows how to create it. And then the whole nightmare of static properties and methods goes away.

Comment: @awnos `Hardcoded_API` the class name or an instance of it?